# Principle of physics used in the lift of skateboard

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life, free-body-diagram

What is the principle of physics used in this popular stunt?
Initially, I thought aerodynamics due to an increase in the angle of attack, but its magnitude is not sufficient to balance the whole body and skateboard. Please, can anyone help me to get about it?

- Animation:

  [image: stunt]

Comment: @EricDuminil if you think about it all and Ollie is, is; use your back foot to slam the tail on the ground. Then immediately jump. Your body and the board will go up in to the air, and all your feet do is prevent the board from flying away, and keeping it under you. (Also I am not convinced that Rodney Mullen abides by the natural laws of physics, he's too good)

Comment: I think the answer to this puzzle must rely on the elasticity of SOMETHING in the problem. My guess is that is relies on the elasticity of the skateboard trucks. If not only that then the elasticity of the wheels, deck or the ground itself.  If all 4 of those things are perfectly rigid I think an ollie would be impossible. None of the answers mention this elasticity at all.

Comment: @jgerber it's much easier to ollie with a new board than with an old one, even if the griptape is replaced, so the elasticity of the tail seems to play a role indeed. The board bounces back up in the air, so to say. I don't think it's needed for an ollie, though, since it's possible to ollie without slamming the board on the ground. The trucks are only relevant for the seesaw motion, and their elasticity is irrelevant IMHO. Which material do you propose for a perfectly rigid board?

Comment: @EricDuminil imagine a slab of steel maybe an inch thick like a skateboard deck. Then instead of trucks imagine there are two blocks of steel extruded down from the deck. These blocks have a hole through them so that an axle can be placed with extremely tight bearings so that the axle has no slop within the housing. Could you ollie on such a board? My hypothesis is that it can't be done because the steel has too little elasticity. That is, the energy from the skaters jump can't be efficiently transferred into the compression of the board to cause it to pop off the ground.

Comment: There are a lot of experts in physics here who are not experts in skateboarding and I think they are theorizing without knowing enough about the actual technique of the Ollie. I suggest you may find much more detail about how an Ollie works by seeking videos that show how to perform one. That should give you some clues about the important physics principles behind the Ollie and also help you evaluate which answer(s) you find valuable in terms of correlating with the actual technique.

Comment: This skater actually points out the worn patch on his shoe that is the result of the Ollie foot drag abrading his front foot shoe. The foot drag is critical: https://youtu.be/EdVueeaNAK0?t=222 And later he shows the foot drag practice: https://youtu.be/EdVueeaNAK0?t=395 He's not a physicist (as far as I know), but he does say "the drag up is what is going to actually lift your board up into the air."

Comment: Here's a slow motion video that may be helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jig3uiYsb4w. @ToddWilcox I think I see what you're saying. The friction of dragging the front foot "up" the board actually puts a friction force on the board against gravity which could actually pull it off the ground. I can see that being a factor. It sounds like you're suggesting if my steel board had a frictiony surface one would still be able to ollie on it but if the surface was smooth it would be impossible. Do you think you could ollie on a regular board with no grip on the deck and a smooth surface?

Comment: Also here is someone performing a kickflip on a 2x4: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxfEzB6PHxw

Comment: @jgerber Obviously grip helps but the Ollie was invented in a time when the fashion was to not have grip across the whole top of the board. Note that popular skate shoes (and this was true back in the 70s and 80s as well) have the rubber sole extended up next to the toes, so the sides of the shoes add some friction. With a painted wooden deck and shoes like that I'm sure one could Ollie acceptably (and many skaters have). Putting grip all over the top of the board just makes it easier to get more air.

Comment: @BruceWayne Your explanation is not quite correct. The front foot plays a part in making the board lift higher by dragging upward against the nose. It's not _technically_ required to do an ollie, but it's essential to getting any sort of useful height from an ollie. Mastering this is the difference between a beginner doing an "ollie" and a pro doing an _ollie,_ if you know what I mean.

Comment: @user91988 - Agree 100%. Just wanted to keep it as simple as possible for the comment [although thinking about it, I shouldn't have left out the front foot bit. Arguably, without that, you're not ollieing, just jumping with style].  Thanks for pointing that out.  (And I know what you mean, personally, I always looked up to Jeremy Wray for learning how to ollie like a god).

Comment: whoever makes a time differential analysis of this video to find the forces on the skateboard “experimentally” gets a bounty from me...

Comment: *"use your back foot to slam the tail on the ground. Then immediately jump."* It's actually the opposite: jump, then the moment you get weightless on your feet, immediately slam the tail on the ground... then drag the front foot up til it locks in the nose pockets, then bend the back knee and *push the front foot forward* (this is what makes the tail stick to the back foot). Popping+dragging up is only half of the smooth, continuous move that is the Ollie.

Answer (score 51):

The skateboard is able to lift off the ground because of the momentum imparted to it by the skateboarder pushing down on the kicktail. The skateboard acts as a lever around the rear wheels, so when the kicktail is pushed down, the center of mass of the skateboard rises up. If you do this fast enough, the skateboard's center of mass gets enough upward momentum to lift the entire skateboard off the ground.

To set up a similar experiment, lay a ruler or pencil so it hangs over the edge of a table a small amount, hit down on the free end, and watch it fly up into the air. You may notice that the object not only flies up but also across the room toward the end you hit. The impulse imparts both vertical and horizontal momentum, which you can see in the first part of the skateboard clip as the center of the board moves both upward and backward.

The skateboarder then uses their front foot to stop this horizontal/rotational motion of the board and keep it under their feet, which is possible because the skateboarder has much more mass/inertia than the board. Because the skateboarder is tens of times as massive as the board, they are easily able to manipulate its momentum with their body, while changing their own momentum relatively little (if you look closely, you can see that both the skateboard and skateboarder do, in fact, land slightly *behind* the point of liftoff). If they just stomped on the kicktail without doing anything else, the board would arc upwards and backward, flipping end over end through the air.

There is nothing related to aerodynamics at play here, this trick could be performed exactly the same way in a vacuum.

EDIT: There seem to be some other factors at play that I've missed here. In particular, the front foot can add some lift to the board as it slides forward to the nose. As the board leaves the ground and rotates up into the front foot, it produces a normal force, which allows the front foot to impart a frictional force parallel to the surface of the board. This won't get the board off the ground in the first place (since friction is always parallel to the board), but once the board is oriented somewhat upright, the board can be pulled further upward by the front foot. Thanks to @Todd Wilcox for pointing this out.

Comment: I think the kicktail also bounces a bit when it hits the ground.

Comment: As someone who has mostly learned to Ollie, this is missing something perhaps minor, but in my experience non-trivial. The drag of the front foot up the length of the board actually is an important part of the lift. If you try to learn to Ollie without the front foot drag, it will be much harder. Further evidence of the importance of the front foot drag is given by the application of grip tape along the length of the board making it easier to Ollie.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The front foot drag is only to maintain stability. The board can be lifted off the ground without the foot drag.

Comment: There is a significant participation from the spring action of the rear axle and board. You are also loading a spring with the first downward motion, which is released when you jump.

Comment: `...which is possible because the skateboarder has much more mass/inertia than the board`  And also because skateboard decks are covered in a super-high friction material that allows lateral grip with very small normal forces.

Comment: @ToddWilcox As someone who has never ridden a skateboard, I'm not sure I follow. Surely the front foot isn't pulling the board upward? It looks like it barely makes contact until it hits the front kickflip. Friction on the front foot will be important to start the counter-rotation which pulls the back end of the board up, but I'm seeing very little contact in the GIF as the front foot slides up.

Comment: @NuclearWang The front foot is definitely pulling the board upwards. Check out the videos linked in my comments on the original question.

Comment: @StianYttervik I thought so too. I didn't think that every ollie required striking the back part of the board on the ground.

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks, I'm clearly not a skateboarder.

Comment: @StianYttervik do you have any source for your claim that the truck is acting as a spring? It seems way too rigid for that, especially compared to the wooden deck.

Comment: @NuclearWang no problem. I love the discussion, with every user bringing a different percentage of skater/physicist to the table. Your answer is good now BTW, I'm just not sure the question is settled. Further research is required :)

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs slamming the ground with the tail is indeed not required. You can stop the seesaw motion just before, and the rest of the board will still be airborne, just not as high as with a powerful pop. I'll try to find a corresponding slow mo video. Note that it doesn't imply that the truck is acting as a spring.

Comment: @EricDuminil If you look at the video, there is significant flex in the axles and the board. Having used one, a long ass time ago (the 90s), I can only offer anecdotal evidence.

Comment: @StianYttervik There is no spring action to the trucks themselves. Trucks are thick cast aluminum with steel or titanium axles. Anything you think you're seeing related to that in the video is perception/illusory. There most certainly is "loading" of the board.

Comment: The front foot friction and motion is a CRITICAL, not minor, component to an ollie. That motion is not just to maintain control of the board. There are loads of videos out there that explain how this trick works already. If you have any specific questions I may be able to help out with, please let me know. I've been ollie-ing for 32 years now.

Comment: I don't think the front foot provides any significant lift. I have been skating my entire life and I know something about physics as well. Think about tricks like a kickflip or a pop-shove it. In these maneuvers, the front foot 'pushes' the tail up far less than in an ollie, but professional skateboarders can do these tricks and acheive near or equal height. The forces on the skateboard provided by the front foot might provide some upward momentum, but it is many orders of magnitude less than the tail popping and jumping actions.

Comment: Oh boy the front foot *does* a lot of work, and actually provides *most* of the lift. 1/4 through the upward motion, the front foot is dragging up and locking into the nose pocket. About halfway through the upward motion, the front foot is moving forward (and slightly down), which moves the tail end of the board and center of gravity most of the way up! The first 1/4 is mostly about having the nose come backwards and the deck tilt vertically towards the front foot: it's entirely possible to lift a board without having the tail hit the ground a.k.a pop, you're just limited by the board angle.

Comment: Case in point, it’s entirely possible to Ollie out of manuals (a.k.a wheelies), or nose or tail slides, without popping but just keeping enough pressure to maintain front foot grip.

Comment: Btw there are videos on Youtube of people doing ollies without griptape on the board.

Answer (score 33):

**Updated Answer** based on comments by @ToddWilcox that actually know more than me about this.

The answer by @NuclearWang is correct, but I wanted to illustrate the process a bit. At least the initial part that sets things up for the stunt.

- Stage I

  [image: Stage-I]

  At this stage, the foot pushes downwards, but the reaction from the ground is greater because the center of mass (yellow dot) must move upwards, due to the kinematics of where the pivot is. For the whole time before the riders foot touches the ground, the center of mass of the board is accelerating upwards (acquiring vertical momentum)
- Stage II

  [image: Stage-II]

  This is the part I missed originally. The back foot causes rotation which is resisted by the front foot, while the foot is sliding upwards causing the sliding friction to add to the lift on the skateboard. This is important as kinematically the rotation of Stage-I can only lift the center of mass so much, and then it stops. To accelerate upwards more, a lift force is needed.
- Stage III

  [image: Stage-III]

  Once enough vertical velocity (yellow arrow) is accumulated by the center of mass and the end of the board strikes the ground, this reaction causes the wheel to lift off. At this point, if the board was allowed to continue to rotate it would pivot about its end launching itself between the rider's legs (not pleasant). At this point the rider's other foot stops the rotation with a slight nudge, leaving only the vertical motion allowing for the board to lift off completely.
- Stage-IV

  From this point on the rider has to actively maintain the orientation of the board as it comes down so that it lands in a way where they can continue riding on it. Overall this stunt involves a carefully practiced choreograph of pushes and pulls on each leg to make the board leap into the air.

Comment: Why doesn't the skateboard rotate clockwise when the clockwise torque is higher in stage 1?

Comment: @RyderRude - good question. Since the board accelerates CCW it must mean the net torque about the center of mass must also be CCW. This will happen as long as $$a > b \left( 1 + \tfrac{W}{F}\right)$$ where $a$ is the distance from the COM to the foot, $b$ the distance to the wheel (pivot), $W$ is the weight of the board and $F$ is the force pushing down at **A**. Resulting angular acceleration CCW is $$\ddot{\theta} = \frac{ F (a-b) - b W}{I+m b^2}$$

Comment: Sadly, this answer is wrong.

Comment: The friction of the forward foot dragging up the length of the board is critical to getting air in an Ollie. I wouldn't say this answer is wrong but it is certainly incomplete. The best answer would combine knowledge of the actual technique with knowledge of the physics behind each aspect of the technique. This answer is missing the physics behind why the foot must be dragged in order to perform an Ollie. There should be many videos available online that instruct on the importance of the foot drag in the Ollie.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I guess the friction of the front foot adds life. Hadn't noticed it before, but now I do. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Also see the comments I added to the question itself. There is a video linked that talks about the foot drag.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I should not type in the dark. My comment should have been "the friction of the front foot adds **lift**".

Comment: @ToddWilcox I made updates to my answer based on your comments, Thank you again.

Comment: Downvote changed to upvote. :-)

Comment: *To accelerate upwards more, a lift force is needed.* Yes. But does it provide significant upthrust? Evidence says no. Because this drag is diagonal, there must be horizontal motion as well. But in the gif we can see that the horizontal motion is negligible.

Comment: John, you're a bit short on step IV, which is critical: the front foot, now being locked against the nose in the front pocket, pushes forward (and slightly down). This makes the tail-end of the board lift up against the back foot *with very little effort*. See this video, especially what the guy says from 4:14 onwards: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsMioe54fSI

Comment: @Lloeki that is a subtle differentiation with step III which the front foot helps lift the board and helps control the orientation.

Comment: Can't you ollie without having grip tape on the board though (there must be videos of this as well)?  Somehow the friction from the grip tape must be helpful to the motion without being essential.

Answer (score 8):

Let us first examine all possible mechanisms for forces that have an upward component.

1. Lever mechanism
2. Flex in the tail
3. Reaction of the wheel
4. Front foot drag

Out of all these obviously the lever mechanism causes the most upthrust. This is backed up by the fact that this portion of the ollie makes the largest displacement.

Flex of the tail (mainly the J-shaped ones) could cause a reasonable  upthrust. But it isn’t a necessity. Same with the reaction of the wheel.

Now coming to the front foot drag. Due to the board being diagonal for the portion of the front foot drag, any lift provided will be **diagonal**. This means that the board must have gain a forward momentum as well. Since in the gif presented by OP there isn’t significant forward momentum, we can say that the lift provided by the foot dragging is negligible.

However the **foot drag is essential** for the ollie. Just not for the upthrust. To keep the board from over shooting it’s backwards rotation, there has to be a mechanism to keep it in check. Moreover without the front foot drag, there would only be one point of contact between the boarder and the board which makes the system highly unstable.

Here’s [video evidence](https://youtu.be/mZrfgJzqrKo) thanks to Eric Duminil’s comment under [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/575021/201709) that shows that the front foot drag isn’t essential for upthrust.

[image]

Comment: You’re confusing the sign on momentum (p) with the change in momentum (delta-p). P can still be negative (moving backwards) while delta-p can be positive (ie forward).

Comment: No I’m not. In this case the CoM has no backward momentum to begin with.

Comment: Everyone who says “looking at the gif/analyzing/checking the free body diagram makes it clear the front foot drag is only a minor component” has clearly never tried to actually Ollie on a board, IMHO.

Comment: @ToddWilcox there’s video evidence indicating that the front foot drag is not needed for lift. Whether I can perform an ollie is irrelevant. Opinions don’t matter in science. Observations do.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: The way I see it : front foot drag is needed in order to level out the board, otherwise the back wheels stay too low to ollie over anything useful. The board itself can be pretty high without drag, but it doesn't bring much if it's almost vertical. The most upthrust definitely comes from the pop, though, while the drag rotates the board, without changing the height of the center of gravity of the board much. For example, it's possible to achieve very high pop shove-its, hardflips or pressure flips without the front foot doing anything.

Comment: Eric, the question is: "How does a Ollie work?", not "How to set a board airborne?", the latter for which there are of course many ways, like that pressure flip. The Ollie movement is a finely timed movement involving tilting the board, dragging the front foot towards the nose and locking it along the front pockets, then pushing the front foot horizontally and slightly down to lift the tail. The goal of the Ollie is to clear higher obstacles than possible with just popping, with minimal effort. See here, especially starting at 4:14: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsMioe54fSI

Answer (score 4):

Others here have given great answers about the physics behind this, but I would like to describe the actual approach of this skateboard stunt known as an Ollie. I'm a skateboarder myself and I regularly use this maneuver to jump onto and over various obstacles including curbs, boxes, and metal rails. Think of the skateboard as a simple seesaw in a way. Weight on one end tilts it down, and weight added to the other end levels it out, although the actual process is a little more complicated and takes thousands of attempts to master.

An Ollie starts with the rider jumping up and pushing the tail downwards in a snapping motion with the back foot. This causes the skateboard to pop up to an extent and start to stand up on it's tail. The actual "lift" of the skateboard is mainly generated by the front foot dragging across the top of it to pull it upwards with the body. Once the front foot hits the nose of the board, the foot is moved forward to level the board out in the air. Doing so allows the board to stay as close to the feet as possible to maintain full control over the stunt throughout the entire process. A lot of beginners will forget to move the front foot up/forward which leads to the board briefly rising up on the tail and then falling back down without leaving the ground.

Notice the position and angle of the front foot before the jump is initiated. The further back the front foot is, the more the board will raise up with the jump as this allows the board to stand up more ("increase in the angle of attack") before being pulled upwards with the front foot. Having the foot slightly angled makes it easier to keep the outside of the foot in contact with the board as the foot is moved upwards and forward.

Comment: I'm not conviced that the foot-dragging is really the main way you lift the skateboard. Even if the board got angled to 90° by the tail-snap, the force vector would have to point as much forwards as up, because the griptape has a limited coefficient of friction. I.e., you would inevitably kick the board forward, away from you. That's not saying front-foot pulling isn't relevant part of a good ollie (which I never managed myself), but it can only be an extra contribution after the rear-foot flick imparted an up- and backwards momentum on the board.

Comment: Contrast this with a bicycle bunny hop, where not only the part of the front foot is taken by the hands on the handlebars so it _is_ possible to pull without throwing the bike away forwards (which is actually considered bad technique), but more importantly the feet stay on the pedals, titled forwards, and thus pull the low part of the bike back, counteracting the hands' forward force component. On a skateboard this only helps to a much more limited extend – the rear foot on the angled-up tail _could_ pull the board back, but this runs into the same problem with limited coefficient of friction.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If the other answers were true, you could ollie with a teflon board and teflon shoes. You can't.

Comment: Note that the board does leave the ground if you pop the tail hard enough, without doing anything with your front foot. It's not high and it's not horizontal, but the board is definitely in the air.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I tried to teach myself to Ollie for some time following the reasoning of the incorrect answers. Then I watched a video about how to Ollie and learned about the foot drag. That made all the difference. My experience is that the foot drag is critical, not merely augmenting. You are correct that a challenge of the foot drag is not pushing the board away. That is a problem of an incorrect foot drag. An Ollie with no drag does not work very well. An Ollie with the foot drag is how you get actual air. Answers not involving friction are incomplete at best.

Comment: @abalter you certainly _can_ ollie without griptape. https://youtu.be/9VwL7ATizDA?t=262 Although he describes it as “even the smallest movements, like, your foot always feels like kinda slipping off a banana shell” he actually gets perfectly good ollies out of it. So friction can't be _that_ important, [Someone even did it with wet bare feet on a _buttered_ board](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-C9UQtkbnI).

Comment: — I think it's actually not about the friction at all, just about quickly getting your foot to the front of the board. At first the foot needs to be far enough back so the board can flick up fast unhindered, but then very shortly afterwards it needs to be on the front to stop the board rotating further (à la Impossible). So, it _is_ necessary to do the fast movement of the front foot, but the friction contributes at most a little bit to the air you're getting. And the grip tape's responsibility is just to provide _control_ and a reliable feel.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Fascinating videos. I'd love to see pros trying their best at ollieing while leaving out important parts of the ollie (pop, slide, jump, push,) or parts of the skateboard (tail, nose, griptape, wheels, trucks). It would be helpful in order to troubleshoot bad ollies. I think good skaters have troubles making bad ollies again because their muscle memory is so strong.

Comment: @leftaroundabout that’s right. Friction doesn’t play a significant role in upthurst. If it did there would be significant forward motion as well since the board is diagonal (as pointed out in my answer). Like you pointed out, it’s more for control.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish The forward motion is kept in check by the rear foot friction holding the board in place and once the front foot kicks out it is brought back to referrer the board under the skater. So the forward force that is imparted on the board by the diagonal foot drag is balanced out by a backwards force.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so hard to understand what causes the upward jump (of course you have to jump in the right way to provide a torque on the board; that's something that one learns instinctively in time). But why does the board stays all the way close to the boy's feet?
As you can see in the clip, by pushing with his right (left in the clip) against the back of the skateboard, which causes the board to rotate. With his left foot, he stops the rotation and the reaction of the board is to stop rotating (it has to conserve it's kinetic energy though, so the rotational kinetic energy is converted into kinetic energy of a linear moving object, which can clearly be seen in the clip; the motion of the board starts with rotating and ends up moving linearly, staying parallel to the surface) thereby being able to stay close to his feet. The right (left in the clip) side of the board after the reaction, moves upwards after the guy has stopped it with his left foot.

Answer (score 0):

The critical element is a conversion from angular to linear notion via an impulse created by pinning first the back wheel then the back tip then releasing back tip. I think @nuclearwang answer is very close but not clear enough.

Look carefully at the video and notice that until the back tip of the board touches the ground, the board is purely rotating around the back wheel. There is no horizontal movement of the back wheel before the back tip hits the ground, the wheel stays in place (although a small amount of horizontal motion would be fine - it would just take away from the attainable height).

So the answers that show an arrow up for center of mass, before back tip hits ground, are wrong. The center of mass is moving in an arc around the back wheel.

Then the back tip hits the ground. Let's call this time Tc. This event is critical, as the ground cannot move, so when it hits the ground it has to stop; *all momentum, which is purely angular before Tc, is transferred to the back wheel, as a force normal to the surface*. This basically converts some angular momentum to linear.

[[Image here to be added later - the app gives error when I try to upload it]]

But not all of it. Basically from Tc onwards, the skateboard would lift and rotate if you did nothing else to it. This includes *removing the force you were applying at the back*.

Then by applying the right amount of force at the front the board after the back wheel has left the ground, the angular rotation can be decelerated to 0.

What takes a lot of time to learn is coordinating the removal of force at the back so the back can lift off the ground, with application of force at the front sufficiently soon after the lift off, in the right amount to decelerate rotation.

Interestingly, having that little kink near the end of the board means you can get higher angular momentum at time Tc. Indeed it takes less time for straight tail to hit ground, than a tail with an upwards kink, hence more time to apply force at the tail hence greater velocity reached at time Tc. This velocity goes to 0 at Tc, thus the greater this velocity the greater the counter impulse force that will be applied at the back wheel at Tc.

I don't have my computer here but I'll see if I can sketch something to illustrate these.

Answer (score -1):

I have an answer totally different than all the others. Odds might be low that it is right but I want to throw it into the ring.. I came up with this answer after watching many of the videos in the various answers and comments but will refer only to the video in the question.

disclaimer: I can't do an ollie. I tried years ago but could never nail it, so take what I say with a grain of salt. Some of my comments will be peppered by what I personally found difficult about the trick when I was trying to learn it.

Question: If I drop or throw something on the hard ground why does it bounce back up?

Answer: Assume the ground is a rigid body and doesn't move. If I drop something on the ground that means it initially has kinetic energy. Let's assume there aren't appreciable friction losses (so that the thing I am dropping isn't squishy, imagine dropping something like a bouncy rubber ball or steel ball as opposed to a blob of pudding). Well, after the ball hits the ground it could just stop instantaneously. But this would violate conservation of energy. Where does the energy go? The answer is that the ball (bouncy ball or steel ball) compresses slightly and the kinetic energy (which came from gravitational energy) is converted into compression energy. The ball then decompresses accelerating upwards, regaining kinetic, and then eventually gravitational potential energy.

How do I think an ollie works? In short, the skater uses their front foot to thrust their body upwards while almost simultaneously using their back foot to "throw" the board at the ground. If the timing and forces are all right the skater continues upwards and the board hits and bounces (or pops) off the ground following the rider into the air.

In more detail, follow along with video in question:

1. Rider is standing on skate board. front foot a little forward of the center of the board. Rear foot behind the back axle.
2. Rider compresses legs and then jumps (converting elastic to kinetic energy of their own body). In particular, the skater's body is able to get air due to the jumping because of their front foot which is between the two axles. The front foot is like doing a one legged jump off of regular ground.
3. The rider is also applying a downward force with the back foot. In addition to given the rider upward thrust this foot also serves to put a downward force on the back of the board creating a lever motion about the back wheels. In particular, if the riders front foot is starting to leave the board and the back foot is still applying a force this imbalanced force will cause the board to lever upwards.
4. back of the board is now moving rapidly towards the ground and the skaters front foot is moving upwards because of the jump. The rider must now STOP applying a downward force with their back foot. In the video it looks like this is accomplished by ensuring their back hip is so high in the air (due to the jumping with their front foot) that their back leg is fully extended and unable to apply downward forces before the moment the back of the board hits the ground. With the rider no longer applying downward forces the back of the board is free to hit the ground with high speed causing flexion of the back of the board** (note the cantilevered bend on the front and back of the board, I suspect in addition to grip this gives the board some springyness that helps it "pop") to convert kinetic into elastic energy. The board then bounces or pops off of the ground, following the rider into the air.

I think at this point the main steps to get the board off the ground are described. In fact, the question only asks about the physics to lift the skateboard. I don't think anyone is confused about how the skater manipulates the board in the air by applying forces with their feet.

So how does the board come off the ground? The skater imparts kinetic energy to the board and then when the board hits the ground that kinetic energy is converted into spring energy which is converted back into kinetic energy and then finally gravitational energy as the board rises up. The trick seems to be* making sure the skaters feet are moving upwards already by the time the board is ready to bounce up into the air.

Regarding the toe drag: Some of the authors in this post make compelling arguments for the toe drag, but alas, after looking at many of the videos I have to say that I'm not convinced it is the main mechanism for getting the board off the ground. Rather, I think the toe drag is probably a very useful technique for skaters to 1) effectively manipulate and control the position and alignment of the board while the skater and the board are airborne and 2)  perhaps it helps get the timing right for the jump and release of downward force with back foot. That said, it is certainly plausible that the toe drag does apply some upward fore on the board and helps keep the rider's feet registered with the board throughout the air to microcorrect for differences in jump speed of the rider and board. I just don't think the toe drag could provide enough force to get the board that high in the air given how small the friction force must be and how heavy the board is.

*At least this is the part that sort of gave me trouble when I was trying to do an ollie in the past.

**See [1:26 in the skateology video](https://youtu.be/mZrfgJzqrKo?t=86), it looks like there is also some spring energy which is loaded into the trucks that provides some pop at the moment the board pops off the ground.

Answer (score -2):

In the video/gif provided, you can plainly see that the board does not actually start to move up into the air until the foot starts dragging.

I puzzled over this for a long time until I watched my son try to learn to ollie and watched instructional videos with him. The physicsy answers here are unfortunate attempts at overthinking.

I worked with my son for a long time on this by watching him very closely and making videos. Getting his board into the air relied entirely on the foot slide.

So, @Max Green's answer is actually correct.

I challenge anyone who disagrees to try to perform an ollie with a teflon deck and teflon shoes. You can't.

What I love about this question is that physicists always try to talk about N3 and the board popping up due to a reaction force. Meanwhile, skilled boarders talk about what they are ACTUALLY doing, which is using friction to slide the board into the air.

And this is amazing because, during the very slow-mo videos they use to support their theory, at the very moment they are discussing how the board pops into the air, they completely miss the boarder's foot sliding up the board imparting upwards momentum through the friction interaction.

### Physics:

- Great video about the intermediate axis theorem, but watch the dude's foot when launching the board. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFRPhi0jhGc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAsdpRHdpDM
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfbiO9dAGBQ

### Boarder:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLrsMflKaDw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLVraCnI5Kc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDZhiMMxlgM

Aaaaaaaaand: [Physics of a skateboard ollie](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3906/physics-of-a-skateboard-ollie)

Comment: This answer should be a comment. My ollies suck, and I somehow never manage to slide my front foot towards the nose. I can still jump over small curbs, though. My front foot just stays 1cm over the board, so the griptape is irrelevant. I know it's not the correct way to perform an ollie, but it does get my board in the air, with only a pop and no slide.

Comment: That's not an ollie. That's tipping up the front of your board to put the wheel on top of the curb using the back wheel as a fulcrum followed by tilting the rest of the board up to level using the front wheel as a fulcrum. There is no "in the air" happening.

Comment: If I edit to make it more of an answer, will you remove the downvote?

Comment: Good to know that you can magically know how my board behaves without ever seeing me ride it. It's definitely in the air and I can jump over small obstacles or clear small gaps. Just to be clear : I definitely agree that the front foot is extremely important. It's wrong to say that the board doesn't leave the ground without the front foot, though.

Comment: Show me a video of you getting the back wheel more than 3 inches off the ground without using your front foot at all, and I'll take it all back.

Comment: https://youtu.be/mZrfgJzqrKo not from me, but much higher than 3 inches, and it shouldn't be a problem to perform with a teflon deck.

Comment: https://download.ericduminil.com/ollie_without_sliding.mp4 Not a proper ollie at all, but it's enough to go over a 9cm high obstacle, and my front foot doesn't do anything. It only touches the board again once I cleared the obstacle.

Comment: Answer is incorrect, see my comments to Max Green. Regarding “you can plainly see that the board does not actually start to move up into the air until the foot starts dragging” – that doesn't prove anything, it's like observing that a car nicks forwards at the moment the driver slams the brakes and concluding that it's the front suspension that causes the braking.

Comment: @abalter I don't think the friction theory holds up to analysis. Friction force is proportional to normal force, which in this case is the force of the sliding foot pressing down on the board. For a net upward force, the vertical component of the friction force must overcome the vertical component of the normal force. Assuming a coefficient of sliding friction to be 0.6 to 0.85 (from Wikipedia, for rubber on concrete), that won't happen until the board reaches an angle of 50 to 60 degrees to the ground. Board angles don't seem to get too much beyond 60 deg in ollies, based on a few videos.

Comment: Furthermore, the Physics Girl / Rodney Mullen video you linked belies the importance of friction. As you said, "watch the dude's foot." By the time the board reaches an angle where there could potentially be a net upward force (around 8:07 in the video), his sliding foot isn't even touching the board! That appears to be the case in the OP's GIF as well, but it's not as clear.

Comment: I think the main value of the slide is to get the foot out to the nose of the board, as far from the CG as possible, so it can exert the maximum torque for a given downward force, and provide an advantageous pivot point. This enables reversing the angular momentum and pivoting the tail up, without too much impact on the upward velocity. The nose angle helps too. Keeping the sliding foot in contact with the board while moving it forward may aid positional awareness and help stabilize the board against flipping, but it doesn't appear to be necessary for gaining altitude, at least not for Mullen.

Comment: @EricDuminil -- Not only is that pressure flip video incredibly well done, it is pretty convincing as well. However, in the mp3 (is that you?) the rear wheel barely comes off the ground, which would have been my prediction exactly.

Comment: @user3065699 -- your argument about the normal force is very physics 201. With grip tape, we aren't talking about microscopic friction. We are talking about large pieces of sand pressing into a rubber shoe sole. Later I'm going to try an experiment where I shove a skateboard up into the air using a shoe held with my hand.

Comment: @abalter I agree for the slow mo video. that's me indeed in the other video. I never claimed to be able to ollie high. Just that my rear wheels are in the air, about 4in high.

Comment: @abalter Large grains of sand may complicate the formulas and increase the friction, but the friction force will still be more or less parallel to the board, and more or less proportional to the normal force. (Try dragging your shoe along the grip tape while pressing down firmly, and again with minimal downward force. Which provides the most resistance?) So there won't be much of a net vertical force component until the board is at a significant angle. And if the foot has left the board by the time that happens, as in the Mullen video, there won't be any vertical force from the sliding foot.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't get _any_ vertical force from friction during the slide, just that it will be insignificant compared to the other forces at play in a typical Ollie. Let us know how your experiment turns out.

Comment: I think the Skateology video destroys the "essential friction" story, because the slow-mo shows the rider's front foot moving slightly *downwards* on the board on some of the flips, while clearly lofting the board a dozen cm or more into the air.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan I don't see the front foot moving downwards on the board. When do you see it in the video? Anyway, you can see at https://youtu.be/mZrfgJzqrKo?t=60 that the front foot doesn't do anything at all during the trick, it merely catches the board once it's done.

Comment: @EricDuminil At about 0:22, it looks to me like the toe slides slightly downward as the front foot comes off the board: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZrfgJzqrKo&feature=youtu.be&t=22